# Is it ever possible to have two boundary event on a task?

Tags: bpmn, boundary

A Boundary Event cancels the task it is on, is it ever possible to set two boundary events on a BPMN task?

I think not but the tool I'm currently using allows it.

I know None-Interrupting events can be multiple, but surely not Boundary Tasks...

Thanks

Comment: As you were saying:
*A Boundary Event cancels the task it is on*:

A boundary event does not *necessarily* cancel the task (again page 258 of the spec), but I might be nitpicking your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the BPMN 2.0 specification, page 258 ([288 in PDF document](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/)):

> (One or more) **Intermediate Events** MAY be attached directly to the boundary of an **Activity**.

As the spec states **one or more**, it explicitly allows two boundary events to be attached to the same activity/task.

Comment: Thanks for the reference material, it's helped a lot with my understanding.  The software I'm using just refers to Boundary and Non-Interrupting Boundary events rather than "Intermediate Interrupting" and "Intermediate Non-Interrupting".  Still, the standard could say, have as many Non-Interrupting events as you want - but only ever allow one Interrupting event.